# Blanking referer for Firefox using PHP

Tags: php

I have a code which should blank a referer:

```
header('Referer: ', true);
header('Location: http://example.com/');
```

However it shows it....

Answer (score 1):

The referrer is set by the browser. You cannot control that on the server side. You would need to create a browser plugin to spoof the referrer.